# db2 reorganize a table

Tags: db2

When I alter a table in **db2**, I have to reorganize it
so I execute the next query:

```
Call Sysproc.admin_cmd ('reorg Table myTable');
```

I m searching an appropriate solution to reorganize a table when it s altered, or reorganize all the schema after making various modifications

Comment: I find scripts helping me resolve this problem, but I wanna find other solutions.

db2 -x "select 'reorg table',substr(rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname),1,50),';' \
from syscat.tables where type = 'T' and tbspace='<tablespace_name>'" > reorg.out 

db2 -tvf  reorg.out

Comment: This kind of question is a database administration question and belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reorg operation is similar to a defrag in hard disk. It frees empty spaces in pages, and eventually it could reorganize data according to an index. Depending on the features, it creates the compression dictionary and compress data.

As you can see, reorg operation is an administrative task, and it is not necessary each time data is modified. A database could run without reorg.

It order to ease this, DB2 included autonomic features like automatic backup, however this doesn't answer you own question. This will only trigger reorg on tables that need that.

- To reorg a table explicitly you need to execute the command reorg http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html
- or via the admin_cmd http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023582.html

Answer (score 8):

You can determine when tables will require a `REORG` by looking at [`SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052897.html):

```
select tabschema, tabname
  from sysibmadm.admintabinfo
 where reorg_pending = 'Y'
```

You may also want to look at the `NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS` column as this may show you additional  tables that don't *require* reorganization due to various `ALTER TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

in db2 config we have:

Automatic reorganization               (AUTO_REORG) = OFF

we can set auto_reorg to on